# ASP.NET MVC AJAX redirecting to new page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a button on a site that should - if clicked - pass some data to the controller and redirect to another view. I tried it with AJAX and realized it doesn't work, because it cannot redirect to another view.

I read some posts that suggested using JavaScript, but there wasn't one where a model is passed to the View as well (Propably I'm just dumb...).

Right now it looks like this:

```
function buttonClick() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Backup/Timestamp',
        data: {iniName: selectedFile}
    });
}

public ActionResult Timestamp(string iniName)
{
    //some code

    return View(Model);
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you want this method 'Timestamp' as post only??

Comment: You could pass the data to the controller, do some logic, and redirect to some another action which will open another view.

Comment: @Stefcho OP is using ajax.  Ajax will never give you redirect result.

Comment: @Stefcho But how can I pass data when redirecting to another action? It doesn't seem like there is an overload that fits my needs.

Comment: @PowerStar If there is another method than Ajax I'd like to try it . What exactly do you mean with "'Timestamp' as post only"?

Comment: Have added my answer for your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of ajax, use the @Url.Action

```
// creates a url like this <domain>/Backup/Timestamp
// This should be in the cshtml
<script>
   var baseurl = '@Url.Action("Timestamp", "Backup")'; 
</script>

// in your custom js file which should added below the baseurl initialization
function buttonClick() {
    location.href = baseurl +'?iniName=' + selectedFile 
}
```

The `@Url.Action()` method is proccessed on the server-side. It will get the path for your action method. Then concatinate the parameter to that url and simply redirect to it

Answer (score 1):

On button click you can just redirect the page to some get method.  So your parameter 'iniName' will be passed as query string instead of request body.

Because if you use **GET** method all the parameter will be passed as query string. If it is **POST** method then it will be send as request body.

So I think in your case Get is enough. So what you need to do is, you need to replace the "buttonClick" function like below.

```
function buttonClick() {
    location.href = '@Url.Action("Timestamp", "Backup")'+'?iniName=' + selectedFile 
}
```

Comment: I don't now whether I do something wrong, but now I get this URL: "http://localhost:32986/@Url.Action(%22Timestamp%22,%20%22Backup%22)?iniName=test.ini"

Comment: @ErikT. is your `buttonClick` function in a seperate js file or in the cshtml itself?

Comment: @adiga it is in a separate js file

Comment: then you should do as the answer i have posted. Create the `var baseurl = '@Url.Action("Timestamp", "Backup")'; ` in the cshtml inside a script tag. Then, add the script tag of your js file which has the buttonClick below it

Comment: @adiga Thx mate. That is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax Action link as:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", // <-- Link text
                 "Edit", // <-- Action Method Name
                 new { id=item.CustomerID }, // <-- Route arguments
                 new {@class="ui-btn", data_val="abc"} // <-- htmlArguments
                )
```

A complete detail for using Ajax Action link can be found at [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/ajax-actionlink-and-html-actionlink-in-mvc/)